# How to disallow nested folders with robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

In my robots.txt I have a disallowing rule like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /_hcms/
```

I want to disallow anything placed inside of `_hcms` and in its nested folders, like `/_hcms/a/` or `/_hcms/b/`.

Should I add a disallowing rule for such subfolders, like

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /_hcms/
Disallow: /_hcms/a/
Disallow: /_hcms/b/
```

Or is the existing rule `Disallow: /_hcms/` makes subfolders disallowed? Or should it even be `Disallow: /_hcms`, without closing slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the existing rule `Disallow: /_hcms/` to disallow anything placed inside of `_hcms` and in its nested folders. The trailing slash is optional and will not affect the behavior of the rule. Therefore, you do not need to add additional rules for subfolders.